# How to get full height to windows for fixed panel <div>

Tags: html, css

I have left and right panel in my layout in HTML. My left panel position is `fixed` and right panel is `absolute` and scroll-able. Now I want my left panel to fill with color to the height of the window as it is fixed. How to make my left panel fill with color to the bottom of the window.

Comment: Show sample code also

Comment: Add the code you tried !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because we don't know your HTML structure nor your CSS code, I tried to "mimic" your situation since you didn't provided any code, which certainly you should of had done I really wonder how your question still alive and haven't been deleted.

However you may achieve it using one of the following methods:

1. Set `height:100%` to the left panel like this
    [**JS Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/ebhkwp1g/)

   ```
   #left-panel { height:100%; position: fixed;}
   ```

---

2. Making use of the [viewport units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) `vh` and `vw`, where `100vh` is full window height, just like this:
   [**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/ebhkwp1g/1/)

   ```
   #left-panel { height:100vh; position: fixed; }
   ```

---

3. You can set `top:0` and `bottom:0` instead of setting the `height` property, like this: 
   [**JS Fiddle 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/ebhkwp1g/2/)

   ```
   #left-panel { top:0; bottom:0; position: fixed; }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your solution solved my problem. Thanks alot.

Comment: You welcome and I'm glad it helped, just next time you ask a question, please consider creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others can help you much better

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css to the right DIV.
Also, have some fixed height to the right DIV.

```
.container-props {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

This will add a scroller to the right DIV.
I think this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I am not looking exactly what you have suggested. I am getting scrollbar for the right panel and it is scrolling the right panel only with fixed header. Actually I want my left panel height adjusted to the windows height so that i can fill that part with the color in my left panel. `100% height` is not working for left panel. I want height that will adjust to the windows bottom so that i can fill with some color in it and while scrolling the right panel it looks constant in left panel.

Comment: Then why didn't you post your code since you have it, there're many people on here ready to help but you're not helping them to help you, it could be hard to do the guesswork instead of just tweaking provided code... actually if you agree about the guesswork, I have three ways to fix your problem.

Comment: May be you can set the height of the left div same as right div.
`$('#leftDiv').height($('#rightDiv').height())`;


As you mentioned that you are getting the scroller. But I guess it's a browser level scroller and not the div level.